# Div bgcolor to change when body bg color changes javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, background-color

I have managed to put together some great code for a small project I am doing, I already managed to create a page background that changes color, with a line of text that also changes when the page background color changes.

Using the same javascript I wonder if it is possible to have a div in the body of the page that changes its background color (to a different color than the page background) every time the page background color changes.

Below is my javascript

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

element = $("#testElement");
var arr = ['hi','hello ','how ','are ','you ']; 

var i = 1; // localizing scope of this variable (not necessary)
setInterval(function(){
    element.removeClass("color"+i);
    console.log(i);
    i++; // missing semicolon here
    if(i == 5)  i = 1;
    element.addClass("color"+i);
    element.text(arr[i]); // change the inner text of element

}, 60000);
})

</script>
```

And here is my html

```
<body id="testElement">
<div id="testDiv"></div>
</body>
```

here is my css

```
.color1{
background: #099;
}

.color2{
background: #F9C;
}

.color3{
background: #6FC;
}

.color4{
background: #C6C;
}
#testdiv {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 115px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

I have learned so much already so thank you all wonderful people in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite something like this...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var bodyElement = $("#testElement"),
    divElement = $("#testDiv"),
    arr = ['hi','hello ','how ','are ','you '],
    i = 1; 

setInterval(function(){
    var oldColor, newColor;

    oldColor = "color" + i;

    i++; 
    if(i === 5)  {
      i = 1;
    }     

    newColor = "color" + i;    


    bodyElement.removeClass(oldColor);
    divElement.removeClass(oldColor);


    bodyElement.addClass(newColor).text(arr[i]); 
    divElement.addClass(newColor);

}, 60000);
})

</script>
```

Or you could rewrite your CSS to apply the color to child elements, something like

```
.color1 {
  background-color:green;
}

.color2 {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying but i think you may have misunderstood the question, I have also included my css code to hopefully make things clearer. I am already using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
element = $("body");
element2 = $("#testElement");
i = 1;
        setInterval(function(){
            if(typeof color != "undefined") { 
            element.removeClass(color)
            element2.removeClass(color2)
            }
            color="color"+Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
            color2="color"+Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
                    while(color==color2) {
                          color2="color"+Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
                    }
            console.log(i);
            i++
            if(i == 5) {
            i = 1;
            }
            element.addClass(color);
            element2.addClass(color2);
        }, 1000);
})
</script>
<style>
.color1{
    background: yellow;
}

.color2{
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

.color3{
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

.color4{
    background: green;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="testElement">Im a test element for testing OMG!!!!?!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

is this what you want?

Comment: yes however you have omitted the changing body text?

Comment: I fear you may have missed my last post, please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have a good code, but you can try this code for dynamic code change when the body background color change . . .

```
<body bgcolor=#652310> <div style="opacity:.5; float:right; height:40%; width:50%; border-radius:15px; background-color:#994248; padding-top:10%; color:white" align="center">

Shenic always rock
                     </div>


<div style="opacity:0.5; float:right; height:40%; width:50%; border-radius:15px; background-color:#232424; padding-top:30%;color:yellow" align="center">

ViniColtinRoy is a lazy boy :-)
                     </div> </body>
```